# Reading text line by line and storing each element in different arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

I have the following contacts.txt file:

```
 0, 0.989246526088, 0.762584552317, 0.989246526088, 0.989246526088, 5, 2, 20, 91, 114, 127
 1, 0.832366089749, 0.67518676348, 0.832366089749, 0.832366089749, 3, 6, 24, 114
 2, 0.923079422275, 0.798673866486, 0.923079422275, 0.923079422275, 5, 0, 65, 73, 91, 114
 3, 0.0820269441841, 0.879379910489, 0.0820269441841, 0.0820269441841, 3, 71, 91, 120
 4, 0.449863833595, 0.985883232333, 0.449863833595, 0.449863833595, 3, 16, 69, 104
 6, 0.887055481253, 0.623261413511, 0.887055481253, 0.887055481253, 5, 1, 25, 87, 100, 114
 7, 0.111156294437, 0.255444048959, 0.111156294437, 0.111156294437, 3, 19, 83, 111
 9, 0.514040361142, 0.373030232483, 0.514040361142, 0.514040361142, 4, 38, 59, 72, 76
 11, 0.597169587765, 0.0286747230467, 0.597169587765, 0.597169587765, 3, 56, 101, 108
 12, 0.89754811115, 0.361667992685, 0.89754811115, 0.89754811115, 3, 86, 92, 126
 13, 0.571528472894, 0.860250953547, 0.571528472894, 0.571528472894, 5, 30, 79, 82,  101, 104
 14, 0.593696200969, 0.680733858699, 0.593696200969, 0.593696200969, 3, 78, 103,   124
```

And so on for 16383 or 16384 lines, depending on the file.

I tried the following code

```
with open('contacts.dat') as infile:
     n, x, y, z, radius, contact_number = [[int(num) for num in line.strip().split()[:5]] for line in infile] 
     neighbours = [[int(num) for num in line.strip().split()[5:]] for line in infile]
```

It does not seem to work.

What I am looking for is,  for each line of the file, the following storing into different arrays:

PER LINE

- zeroth element --> `n` (where --> means "stored in the array")
- first element --> `x`
- second element -- > `y`
- third element --> `z`
- fourth element --> `radius`
- fifth element --> `contact_number`
- remaining elements of the line (if any) --> `neighbours`

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: Can you show an actual example of what the resulting array(s) should be instead of just a prose description?

Comment: I would avoid iterating over the file twice. Put it in one for loop. Also, looks like you're calling `int` on several floats.

Comment: Also, consider using some dummy input data that's more distinctive and readable than just random numbers, like `1, 0.1, 0.11, ...` - or even words instead of numbers when it's not important what the data as seems to be the case.

Comment: Lateral suggestion: are you trying to parse the text file into "parallel lists"? If so, don't, and parse it into a list objects with properties instead. (`namedtuple`s are excellent for this if you don't need mutability.)

Comment: among other things if you did want to iterate twice you need to repostion to the beginning with infile.seek(0) ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your list comprehension -- first and foremost, you are creating a list of lists (with some thousand entries) and trying to assign this list to six variables. Better use a loop instead. Also note that you are casting everything to `int`, while some values are actually `float`s, but the casting fails anyway because the split line still has commas in it.

Since your file contains comma-separated values, I recommend using the `csv` module. This will take care of the splitting and comma-stripping stuff. Also, instead of using one large list comprehension, it might be more readable to extract the values individually, or in groups.

```
import csv
with open("contacts.dat") as infile:
    for line in csv.reader(infile):
        num = int(line[0])
        x, y, z, radius = map(float, line[1:5])
        contact = int(line[5])
        neighbors = map(int, line[6:])
```

Now that the individual values are extracted, all that's left to do is to store them in some data structure, e.g., a list of dictionaries, names tuples, or some special class.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store the columns of your input, but unpacking gives the rows. Transpose it first:

```
def transpose(grid):
    return zip(*grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: NumPy

```
import numpy as np
nparray = np.genfromtxt('contacts.txt',delimiter = ',')
#Where column N is accessed by nparray[:,n]
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach to reading the file using only built-in functions..

`def atonum(x):
  if x.find('.') < 0: return int(x)
  return float(x)
with open(filename) as infile:
  alldata=[[ atonum(y) for y in  x.strip().split(',') ]  for x in infile]`